Least average cost path (distance-agnostic)
I am wondering if there is a straightforward way in ArcGIS Pro to identify the path between two points of least average cost (as opposed to a least cumulative cost). Basically, I want a LCP that is totally agnostic to the number of cells traversed, but prefers to traverse cells which individually have low cost.
I am an archaeologist, and this is for the purpose of identifying possible processional routes, where it may not matter how long it takes to walk, but one would still want to avoid traversing high-cost (sloped) terrain.
Please let me know if I am entirely out of my mind for thinking this is possible, but it seems so simple!

Not sure. But perhaps you could increase the vertical factor in the Optimal Path As Line / Raster tool so traversing high cost terrain is prohibitive.

Just set cells with high cost to NoData  or use exp(cost) so path can always be found

If you're familiar with creating a cost surface raster using elevation and land use layers or you already have a pre-existing cost surface raster, then the process can be simplified to just two steps using two specific geoprocessing tools: Distance Accumulation(step 1) and Optimal Path as line(step 2). The input requirements for both tools are clearly defined and depicted in the accompanying images.

If you dont know how to create cost surface raster you can follow the link provided https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/creating-a-cost-surface-raster.htm
